# Socket.io client won't display to all users

Tags: python, browser, server, socket.io, client

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);



    socket.on('message', data => {
        const p = document.createElement('p');
        const span_username = document.createElement('span');
        const span_timestamp = document.createElement('span');
        const br = document.createElement('br');
        span_username.innerHTML = data.username;
        span_timestamp.innerHTML = data.time_stamp;
        p.innerHTML = span_username.outerHTML + br.outerHTML +  data.msg 
        + br.outerHTML + span_timestamp.outerHTML;  
        document.querySelector('#display-message-section').append(p);
    });

    // Send message
    document.querySelector("#send_message").onclick = () => {
        socket.send({'msg':document.querySelector('#user_message').value, 
        'username': username});
    } 

});
```

Here is my full client side. I want to get it to show all sent messages to all users, including myself. When I opened another tab and then typed something, the first type won't show what my second tab sent. It is sent in the server but not displayed in the browser.

```
@socketio.on('message')
def message(data):
  print(f"\n\n{data}\n\n")
  send({'msg': data['msg'], 'username': data['username'], 'time_stamp':strftime('%b-%d %I:%M%p', localtime())})
```

This is my minimal server.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `broadcast=True` to the arguments on your send. By default, socketio will only emit to the original caller of the socket function.